# What does facebook mean by active users?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

we are using Facebook Graph API to fetch data from Facebook related to some public pages.
the problem is we are hitting APP rate limit quite often so I was trying to understand what could cause the APP rate limit, I came across the following [documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting#application-level-rate-limiting#applications) from Facebook which explains detailed information about the Rate limit, however, they state the following statement

> The Number of Users is based on the number of unique daily active users an app has.

but I couldn't figure out what do they mean by `daily active users` in our context where we use Facebook developer app to fetch data from Facebook?
I hope I make it clear enough
help me pleae

Comment: An active user is someone who “does” something in your app, whose access token you use to make some API requests.

Comment: @04FS the idea is there is no user will log into our app we are just taking access tokens from our users and then we crawl the data in the background, so actually there is no user that keep using our app, so that we can call it active or inactive user

Comment: As long as you got a valid access token and use it to make a request, they should count as an active user for that day.